# is jquery mobile disabling keyboard apperance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, jquery-mobile

So I have a JQM application I am working on, and have a very strange problem.  I have a text area for the user to input some data.  I display the loading dialog like this `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();`  This is good, but if I try to call this in the success call back `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` suddenly the user input in the text area is disabled.  I have no idea why, and it's driving me insane.  I commented out all of the processing logic to see if it will still happen if nothing but the html would load.  Indeed it does.  Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?  Thanks!

```
$('#pageDiv').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){  
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    //Do more processing stuff (currently commented out)
}
```

and the success callback

```
module.successCallback = function() {
    //Do more processing here (currently commented)
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();  // if I take this out, the keyboard will show...
}
```

NOTE:  THIS IS ONLY HAPPENING IN ANDROID...

Comment: Some additional inputs like OS,device/emulator etc would be appreciated.

Comment: So I actually just stumbled across something after taking a few days off from looking at it.  Apparently it was being caused by setting the footer to fixed.  Then when the user selected the text area, it tried to re-position the footer, therefore hiding the keyboard.  It was a savage cycle...